jax.lax.cond executing both branches instead of just the True branch
I'm encountering an AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute in my Python code using JAX's jax.lax.cond. Here's a simplified version of what I'm trying to do:
from typing import NamedTuple, Optional
import jax

class Node(NamedTuple):
    child: Optional['Node']
    active: bool

node = Node(child=None, active=True)

child_active = jax.lax.cond(node.child is not None, lambda _: node.child.active, lambda _: False, None)

In this code, node is an instance of Node with child set to None and active set to True. According to the documentation, jax.lax.cond should execute only the branch that evaluates to True. However, I'm getting an AttributeError indicating that the False branch is also being executed.
Could someone explain why this error occurs when jax.lax.cond should only evaluate the True branch? Also, what is the correct way to conditionally access attributes of an optional child node like this using JAX?

This is working as expected. Your error is coming up at trace-time, not at runtime. lax.cond will always trace both branches, but then only execute one branch at runtime depending on the runtime value of the condition.
In your case it looks like you’re passing a statically-known condition, so instead you can do this:
child_active = node.child.active if node.child is not None else False

For some discussion of JAX’s execution model, including the concept of tracing, you might start with How to think in JAX.

Thanks @jakevdp. The reason I'm looking into lax.cond is say I have a update_fn like def update_node(node): return node if node.child is not None and node.child.active else node._replace(child=Node(child=None, active=True)) How would I go about making this function jit compatible?

As you mentioned lax.cond would fail as it traces both branches, and the original if else implementation would result in a TracerBoolConversionError.

Using if...else with static conditions like node.child is not None is compatible with JIT. The code above will not result in a TracerBoolConversionError because no traced booleans are involved. If there is relevant code that you did not include in your question, then I'd suggest you edit your question.

If you have a combination of static and dynamic conditions, then you might be able to use a combination of static if…else statements and dynamic lax.cond statements
